# How to add an element inside a set using iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

Following is my code:

```
//adds element j into the same set as element i
void addelem(int j, int i, set<set<int>> s)
{
    for (auto itr1 = s.begin(); itr1 != s.end(); ++itr1) {
        for (auto itr2 = (*itr1).begin(); itr2 != (*itr1).end(); ++itr2) {
            if (*itr2 == i) {
                (*itr1).insert(j);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But I'm getting an error in this line:

```
(*itr1).insert(j);
```

Error reads:

> no instance of overloaded function matches argument list C++

Comment: Contents of a set cannot be modified, they are effectively `const`. You are attempting to modify a value in the set (by modifying the set that's in the "outer" set), which is not allowed. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Understandable, but in my case, I cannot erase it / temporarily store its contents elsewhere. Is there any way around this?

Comment: "cannot erase it / temporarily store its contents elsewhere" why not?

Comment: @idclev463035818 because as you can see above, I am implementing it on a set of sets, and I get that error if I try to use .erase() or .swap() with my iterator variables.

Comment: you have to remove the inner set from the outer one before you can modify it and then insert it again

Comment: @idclev463035818 ok, could you give me an idea of what function or method I could use to do that?

Comment: @Zainab its explained in the duplicate. You have a `set<set<int>>` and you want to modify one element of the `set<int>`, so you have to first remove that set from the `set<set<int>>` then remove the `int` from that `set<int>` and then insert them back. Maybe you are confused because currently you are focusing on the `set<int>` only

Comment: No, there's no simple "way around this". This is how `std::set` works. Whatever you're trying to accomplish here, you will need to find some other way to do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. Appreciate the input.